# Is there a Java LinkedList method to use as a ring list?

Tags: java, list, linked-list

If I have a LinkedList:

```
Value A B C D E F
Index 0 1 2 3 4 5
```

I want to reorder the list or an Iterator for example at D(index 3) to be the new head but keep the order like:

```
Value D E F A B C
Index 0 1 2 3 4 5
```

Is this a functionality that can be achieved with LinkedList out of the box, basically realizing a ring? Is there another class that offers this already implemented?

Comment: Is it possible that you don't rearrange the elements? You can change the index for accessing the elements by doing something like `(i + offset) % length` (be careful with negative numbers).

Comment: `Collections.rotate(...)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`Collections.rotate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#rotate(java.util.List,int)) for classes that implement the `List` interface:

```java
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F");
Collections.rotate(list, 3);
System.out.println(list);
```

**Output**:

`[D, E, F, A, B, C]`

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not possible using any standard class in Java. You have to create you own implementation base on any ordered random access collection like: Array, List.

Following solution probably not optimal, but it works and was written in 5 minutes.

```
public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {
    Deque<Character> deque = new LinkedList<>();
    deque.addAll(Arrays.asList('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'));
    System.out.println(deque);
    reorder(deque, 3);
    System.out.println(deque);
    reorder(deque, 3);
}

public static void reorder(Deque<Character> deque, int offs) {
    offs %= deque.size();

    for (int i = 0; i < offs; i++)
        deque.add(deque.removeFirst());
}
```

**Output:**

```
[A, B, C, D, E, F]
[D, E, F, A, B, C]
```

***P.S.** As you can see the method accepted `Deque`, so you could use any implementation of this interface.*

Comment: I had the same idea as you, but would have used an [`ArrayDeque`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayDeque.html) instead of a `LinkedList`.

Comment: @AlexR I suppose that initial list is modifiable and no need to create another one.

Comment: @AlexR: The only advantage of `LinkedList` over `ArrayDeque` is that it also implements `List`. `ArrayDeque` is better as a pure double-ended queue. It doesn't make the answer wrong.

Comment: @Nikolas I didn't mean to say it's wrong. The documentation only states that "[ArrayDeque] is likely to be faster .... than LinkedList when used as a queue." which this answer does.

Comment: @Nikolas in the question it says that we have a `LinkedList` - not anything else.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a really simple way using [`List::subList(int fromIndex, int toIndex)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList-int-int-):

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F");

int index = list.indexOf("D"); // or a fixed number, depends on your implementation

List<String> newList = new ArrayList<>();
newList.addAll(list.subList(index, list.size()));  // right part [D, E, F] first
newList.addAll(list.subList(0, index));            // left part [A, B, C] then
```

The `newList` will contain `[D, E, F, A, B, C]`, however it doesn't use any advantage of the linked structures.

Comment: Space complexity is `O(n)`, time complexity is `3*O(n)` - am I right?